# Jenkins Maven Release with GIT

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, ssh

I got Jenkins set up with SSH connection to Git, using SSH agent and trying to set up a job, which would do Maven Release build. The job is executing following commands

```
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform  
-Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare
```

During deployment with maven-deploy-plugin I run into error,

```
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ uaiContacts ---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 4.151 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-23T11:35:32+01:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 27M/265M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project uaiContacts: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access git@giturl:repo with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access git@giturl:repo using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[INFO] [ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[INFO] [ERROR] roleHint: git@giturl
[INFO] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am not sure why is it saying cannot access and how is it trying to access. As I am aware wagon will be using ssh, so there should not be a problem.

My pom.xml

```
    <build>
         <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </extension>
         </extensions>
    </build>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@giturl:repo</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@giturl:repo</developerConnection>
        <url>git@giturl:repo</url>  
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>release</id>
        <url>git@giturl:repo</url>
      </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: It does not make sense to deploy build artifacts to a git repository. For such things repository manager is the right tool (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva)...

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake. Just installed Artifactory and trying to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deploy the released artifact to a GIT repository. Artifacts are deployed to a central repository such as Artifactory or Nexus, usually by means of HTTP (POST) unless you specify something else.

If you want to deploy using SSH, [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html) link will explain how it's done.